# How to call stopwords from a txt file using wordcloud STOPWORDS

Tags: python-3.x, stop-words, word-cloud

I am extracting a wordcloud from a pdf file. I can extract stopwords from a list but cannot extract using a txt file. I know there is a problem with calling the path to the file.

I have success redacting stopwords using a list but I want to be able to use a txt file for the stopwords as eventually I would like to associate different stopword files for different purposes.

Thanks in advance for the help.

````
#viz libs
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#img libs
from PIL import Image
#binary array lib
import numpy as np
#pdf reader
import PyPDF4

pdfFileObj = open('Test-Resume-Doc.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pageText = (pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()
#set stopwords
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

#can call stopwords from a list as such
#stopwords.update(["word1", "word2", "word3", ...])
#call stopwords from txt file and program executes ignoring txt file, the problem is how the path is run
stopwords.update(['stopwords.txt'])

rsMask = np.array(Image.open('Resume_WordCloud.png'))
#create wordcloud with stopwords
cloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords, background_color="black", mask=rsMask).generate(pageObj.extractText())


plt.imshow(cloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig('path.../PythonPDFRW/Resume_WordCloud_fromPython.png'.format(cloud))
plt.show()```
````

Comment: Ok I've tried reading the text into a readline so splitting the text is the next step? Currently it reads the text file as a single long string...

`text_file = open("stopwords.txt", "r")`
`stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)`
`stopwords.update(text_file.readlines())`

Answer (score 0):

Used a for loop to read each line in file then stripped out the line break \n
It's not elegant but it worked.

````
for line in text_file:
    stopwords.add(line.strip('\n'))
print(stopwords)```
````